# GWT removeClickHandler

Tags: gwt

GWT introduced with version 1.6 handlers to be used instead of listeners.
Now I was used to add and remove those listeners to achieve certain behavior.

But as I move towards using handlers I miss the remove methods.
Like **removeClickHandler** for the click event.

Is there a way to do this, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each `add...Handler` method returns the `HandlerRegistration` interface. This interface contains the `removeHandler()` method. If you want to remove handlers, simple store the returned interface in a variable and call `removeHandler` when you want to remove the handler.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution

```
HandlerRegistration registration = addClickHandler(handler);

...

registration.removeHandler();
```